# Generate multiple Excel workbooks from pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, vba

I am new to Excel Pivot tables and need an expert advise.

I have a Pivot table that can be filtered by multiple units. (say unit 1, unit 2, unit 3 etc...). I want to create multiple excel worksheets from this pivot table and each worksheet should contain information about only one unit. (for example, one worksheet will have data for unit 1 only), second will have data for unit 2 only etc..

I did some research and used "Show report filter pages" which creates multiple tabs but I notice that each tab contains data for all units.

Can anyone help me with this..?

Answer (score 0):

**Show report filter pages** will work as you intended but you have to keep the Filtering Field in **Report Filter** only.